# Adding vs. removing interaction changes significance of single predictors in lm()

Tags: r, statistics, lm

I'm running two types of ANCOVA's in R on the same data. One model includes the interaction term between the two predictors, the other doesn't:

```
model<-lm(trait~size*population, data=d)
model2<-lm(trait~size+population, data=d)
```

When looking at the t-statistics of the first model using summary(model), the interaction term appears non-significant and highly trivial (t-value is -0.14). Similarly, there seems to be no effect of "population" (t = -0.13, p-value = 0.897). However, summary(model2) indicates a quite strong effect of "population" on "trait" (t = -3.3, p-value = 0.0016). How is this possible?

Here are the data:

```
structure(list(ID = c("rat1", "rat2", "rat3", "rat4", "rat5", 
"rat6", "rat7", "rat8", "rat9", "rat10", "rat11", "rat12", "rat13", 
"rat14", "rat15", "rat16", "rat17", "rat18", "rat19", "rat20", 
"rat21", "rat22", "rat23", "rat24", "rat25", "rat26", "rat27", 
"rat28", "rat29", "rat30", "rat31", "rat32", "rat33", "rat34", 
"rat35", "rat36", "rat37", "rat38", "rat39", "rat40", "rat41", 
"rat42", "rat43", "rat44", "rat45", "rat46", "rat47", "rat48", 
"rat49", "rat50", "rat51", "rat52", "rat53", "rat54", "rat55", 
"rat56", "rat57", "rat58", "rat59", "rat60", "rat61", "rat62", 
"rat63", "rat64", "rat65", "rat66", "rat67", "rat68"), population = c("A", 
"A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B"), size = c(39.72, 46.72, 38.37, 40.8, 46.57, 35.93, 
51.69, 40.97, 45.39, 43.67, 43.68, 39.2, 45.07, 42.11, 46.91, 
45.99, 42.43, 41.36, 42.54, 38.41, 42.35, 40.79, 45.32, 43.67, 
46.34, 40.26, 39.09, 49.2, 47.85, 45.14, 42.38, 44.2, 41.22, 
41.52, 45.12, 45.63, 44.15, 40.18, 47.88, 43.86, 42.79, 43.99, 
47.22, 43.78, 41.84, 42.99, 37.9, 44.21, 47.82, 45.26, 45.97, 
44.99, 40.48, 42.27, 43.85, 41.1, 42.11, 41.9, 38.17, 46.08, 
37.75, 40.92, 38.69, 46.34, 39.3, 49.76, 43.69, 37.18), trait = c(3.657, 
4.096, 3.186, 4.286, 3.901, 2.882, 4.666, 4.635, 4.93, 4.264, 
4.329, 3.493, 5.142, 4.859, 4.272, 3.5, 4.199, 4.434, 4.278, 
3.211, 4.382, 3.941, 4.525, 4.547, 4.08, 4.345, 3.827, 4.822, 
4.363, 4.229, 4.063, 4.605, 3.803, 4.008, 4.775, 3.949, 4.308, 
4.048, 4.697, 3.951, 3.488, 3.705, 3.408, 4.458, 3.834, 4.057, 
3.318, 4.04, 4.596, 4.931, 4.294, 3.817, 4.16, 4.304, 3.67, 4.273, 
4.194, 3.461, 3.072, 3.692, 3.019, 3.17, 3.095, 3.785, 3.814, 
4.131, 3.639, 3.385)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-68L))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you have statistical questions in the future, it may be more useful to post them to CrossValidated. That forum is for statistical questions whereas this one is more for coding problems. Maybe someone with the power can migrate this question there, but for now I'm going to answer the question as best I can.

This is a fairly common consequence of modelling interaction terms, for example this discussion on researchgate: https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_interpret_regression_when_an_insignificant_interaction_term_makes_significant_predictors_insignificant

I think it may help to visualize what your model is doing. Here are the effect plots for the model with the interaction term:

```
library(effects)
plot(allEffects(model))
```

[image]

This model predicted separate slopes for size for each of the two levels of population. As such, there is less statistical power when comparing these slopes for the purposes of checking whether the two populations were significant. In particular, look at the confidence intervals of the size plot for population B.

In contrast, let's look at the plot for the model without the interaction term:
`plot(allEffects(model2))`

[image]

The effect of size is predicted without considering the two populations, and you'll notice that the CI is much smaller, as there is more data. Then the effect of population is predicted without considering that the effect of size may change for each population.

Comment: I then wonder, how to best for the interaction term at first place to know whether dropping it or not is ok. Would I do this via lm(trait~size*population) vs. lm(trait~size:population) to test for the interaction term. The latter model produces a highly significance term, the former not. I assume the former is the correct one, as the latter model produces a spurious interaction because of the strong effect of 'size' on 'trait'.

Comment: My second follow-up question concerns your visualization, and the respective interpretation: why is in the model with the interaction term the interaction of only size and population not shown, because size*population test both the interaction as well as the individual effects separately.

Comment: Btw, I tried to migrate this question to CrossValidated, but it did not work. Thanks for the tip though! I will consider this in the future.